# How to get clipboard content origin or generator

Tags: windows, api, winapi, clipboard

My application is consuming HTML from clipboard.

I am trying to find a method that allows to get origin of the content, ideally to have some function that returns one of `enum SOURCE { EMAIL, WORD, EXCEL, WEB, etc. }`

So far I am using two sources of the information:

1. `<meta generator="..." />` that comes in CF_HTML.
2. url of clipboard content (part of CF_HTML data).

But neither one is reliable for identification purposes. For example `generator` equals to `"Microsoft Word 15"` on content coming from MS Word, Windows Mail, MS Outlook. But EXCEL is fine - `"Microsoft Excel 15"`.

I was also trying to get some meaningful info from `GetClipboardOwner()` API but it returns some generic window like "CLIPBOARDWND" or some as such.

So is the question: is there any stable method to get origin meta information of clipboard content?

Update: A bit of context, I am writing personal note taking application in [Sciter](https://sciter.com) where capture source should allow to classify notes properly (see "Attributes"):

[image: Sciter's Notes]

Comment: The clipboard does not care about originators, and does not keep track of that info. As you noticed, the only option is if an originator identifies itself in the data, which is not reliable (not only because multiple apps share the Word engine, but also because CF_HTML does not require it anyway). Clipboard ownership is very short-lived (just long enough to update the clipboard data, or render data on-demand), so `GetClipboardOwner()` is rarely ever useful. In the off-chance it returns a valid `HWND`, you can try using `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` to determine the process ID that it belongs to

Comment: @RemyLebeau Clipboard mechanism does not care, yes, but list of data formats in clipboard is different for each application. I really don't want to go that path though, until there is any well-known data format that can be used as a determinant

Comment: My understanding of clipboard ownership appears to be wrong. When an app places data on the clipboard, the specified window remains the owner of the data, even after `CloseClipboard()` is called (makes sense, so the window can receive delay-render messages related to the data), until the window is closed or a new window is assigned ownership. So `GetClipboardOwner()` is more meaningful than I thought, and my `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` suggestion still stands. Get the owner's Process ID, then query it for its path and filename, then you can guess what the app is based on that info.

Comment: The real question is, why do you need to identify the originator at all? What are you really trying to solve?  This is sounding like a possible [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/156206).

Comment: Why does your note-taking app need to know what kind of app created the clipboard data? Are you going to code your app to recognize every possible email app in existence, or every possible web browser? That is ridiculous. The OS does not classify apps that way (well, it kind of does, but not for purposes of clipboard management). You might have *some* luck if you get the owning process file path+name and then match it up to known registrations in the Registry, such as in `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Clients`. But I suggest you re-think your requirement.

Comment: In a year you would remember the only that it was some funny email that you have noticed.  You should be able to narrow your search to find it. Sacred words in software development "it is a business requirement to store as much reasonable context as possible".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont know if this is old, but you might check this answer: [Get the origin data source with System.Windows.Clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48834117/get-the-origin-data-source-with-system-windows-clipboard)

if you can get the origin object then you can create a login to get what kind of app it is

Comment: Oh, thanks. At least it gives the idea to use `GetClipboardOwner()` API.