# Get the origin data source with System.Windows.Clipboard?

Tags: c#, .net, console, clipboard

I am using `System.Windows.Clipboard` to copy some text, and I would like to know is there a chance to get the origin source,
e.g. a the file where I copyied it from, or the website, folder.... ?

Thanks

Comment: No, the clipboard does not provide that information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Win32 [GetClipboardOwner()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclipboardowner) function can be used to get the Handle of the Window that last placed data into the Clipboard.

You can then pass the returned handle to [GetWindowThreadProcessId()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid) to get the Process ID and Thread ID of that Window.

Back in .Net territory, you can use the Process ID as the parameter to pass to the `System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById()` method, to retrieve the information needed.

> Note that you have to build a 64bit application to fully inspect a 64bit
> process. If your project has the *Prefer 32-bit* option set, some
> information will not be available.

See also:
[How to get the process ID or name of the application that has updated the clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65158907/7444103)

---

Windows API declarations. The overloaded `GetClipboardOwnerProcessID()` wrapper method returns the `ProcessID` of the ClipBoard Owner and, optionally, its Thread ID.

```
public class WinApi
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetClipboardOwner();

    //The return value is the identifier of the thread that created the window. 
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

    //Wrapper used to return the Window processId
    public static uint GetClipboardOwnerProcessID()
    {
        uint processId = 0;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(SafeNativeMethods.GetClipboardOwner(), out processId);
        return processId;
    }

    //Overload that returns a reference to the Thread ID
    public static uint GetClipboardOwnerProcessID(ref uint threadId)
    {
        uint processId = 0;
        threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(SafeNativeMethods.GetClipboardOwner(), out processId);
        return processId;
    }
}
```

The wrapper can be called like this, if you just need the Process Id:

```
uint ClipBoadrOwnerProcessId = WinApi.GetClipboardOwnerProcessID();
```

Or this way, if you also need the Thread Id:

```
uint ClipBoadrOwnerThreadId = 0;
uint ClipBoadrOwnerProcessId = WinApi.GetClipboardOwnerProcessID(ref ClipBoadrOwnerThreadId);
```

Pass the returned value to the `Process.GetProcessById()` method:

```
Process ClipBoardOwnerProcess = Process.GetProcessById((int)WinApi.GetClipboardOwnerProcessID());
    
string ProcessName = ClipBoardOwnerProcess.ProcessName;
string ProcessWindowTitle = ClipBoardOwnerProcess.MainWindowTitle;
string ProcessFileName = ClipBoardOwnerProcess.MainModule.FileName;
//(...)
```

If you copy some text from your browser, the `ProcessName` will be the name of your browser and the `ProcessFileName` the path to its executable.