# How to get the process ID or name of the application that has updated the clipboard?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, process, clipboard

I am creating a clipboard manager in C# and from time to time I experience that the clipboard is being set empty by some application.

This happens in e.g. Excel when deselecting what is just copied, so I need to figure out if the clipboard is empty but **how can I get the application name that updates the clipboard**?

I hope that I somehow can get the `HWnd` handle of the application that updates the clipboard so I can then lookup the process behind it with this code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
public static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);
...

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
{
    switch (m.Msg)
    {
        case WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE:
            // How to get the "handle" HWnd?
            IntPtr handle = ??? <============= HOW TO GET THIS ONE ???

            // Get the process ID from the HWnd
            uint processId = 0;
            GetWindowThreadProcessId(handle, out processId);

            // Get the process name from the process ID
            string processName = Process.GetProcessById((int)processId).ProcessName;

            Console.WriteLine("Clipboard UPDATE event from [" + processName + "]");
            break;
        }
        default:
            base.WndProc(ref m);
            break;
    }
}
```

I would have hoped that I could use the `HWnd` from the `Message` object, but this seems to be my own application - probably to notify the application with this process ID:

[image: This what I get from the Quick View in C# when the clipboard is changed]

If I can get it any other way then this would of course be fully okay also but I would appreciate any insights on this :-)

---

**Solution**

Based on @Jimi's answer then this is very simple. I can just add the below 3 lines to my original code:

```
// Import the "GetClipboardOwner" function from the User32 library
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetClipboardOwner();
...

// Replace the original line with "HOW TO GET THIS ONE" with this line below - this will give the HWnd handle for the application that has changed the clipboard:
IntPtr handle = GetClipboardOwner();
```

Comment: Microsoft's sysmon can do that apparently (https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/microsoft-sysmon-now-logs-data-copied-to-the-windows-clipboard/)  if you just need to know that for debugging...

Comment: For debugging this could maybe be good but I need it in my application as I should to do some action if the clipboard becomes empty. This happens e.g. when you copy something in Excel and then cancel the selection - then it empties the clipboard. My own application also sometimes empties the clipboard for some reason and when it does that then I need to restore the clipboard - but I need to know which application does it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call [GetClipboardOwner()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclipboardowner) to get the handle of the Window that last set or cleared the Clipboard (the operation that triggered the notification).

> [...] In general, the clipboard owner is the window that last placed data in the Clipboard.
> The EmptyClipboard function assigns Clipboard ownership.

There are special cases when a Process passes a null handle to [OpenClipboard()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-openclipboard): read the Remarks section of this function and the [EmptyClipboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-emptyclipboard) function.

> *Before calling EmptyClipboard, an application must open the Clipboard
> by using the OpenClipboard function. If the application specifies a
> NULL window handle when opening the clipboard, EmptyClipboard succeeds
> but sets the clipboard owner to NULL. Note that this causes
> SetClipboardData to fail.*

---

▶ Here I'm using a [NativeWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.nativewindow) derived class to setup a Clipboard listener. The Window that process the Clipboard update messages is created initializing a [CreateParams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.createparams) object and passing this parameter to the [NativeWindow.CreateHandle(CreateParams)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.nativewindow.createhandle) method, to create an *invisible* Window.
Then override `WndProc` of the initialized NativeWindow, to receive [`WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/wm-clipboardupdate) notifications.

The [AddClipboardFormatListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-addclipboardformatlistener) function is used to place the Window in the system Clipboard listeners chain.

▶ The `ClipboardUpdateMonitor` class generates an event when a Clipboard notification is received. The custom `ClipboardChangedEventArgs` object passed in the event contains the Handle of the Clipboard Owner, as returned by `GetClipboardOwner()`, the `ThreadId` and `ProcessId` returned by [GetWindowThreadProcessId()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid) and the Process name, identified by [Process.GetProcessById()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessbyid).

You can setup a `ClipboardUpdateMonitor` object like this:
<sub>This class can also be initialized in `Program.cs`</sub>

```
private ClipboardUpdateMonitor clipboardMonitor = null;
// [...]

clipboardMonitor = new ClipboardUpdateMonitor();
clipboardMonitor.ClipboardChangedNotify += this.ClipboardChanged;
// [...]

private void ClipboardChanged(object sender, ClipboardChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ProcessId);
    Console.WriteLine(e.ProcessName);
    Console.WriteLine(e.ThreadId);
}
```

---

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public sealed class ClipboardUpdateMonitor : IDisposable
{
    private bool isDisposed = false;
    private static ClipboardWindow window = null;
    public event EventHandler<ClipboardChangedEventArgs> ClipboardChangedNotify;

    public ClipboardUpdateMonitor()
    {
        window = new ClipboardWindow();
        if (!NativeMethods.AddClipboardFormatListener(window.Handle)) {
            throw new TypeInitializationException(nameof(ClipboardWindow), 
                new Exception("ClipboardFormatListener could not be initialized"));
        }
        window.ClipboardChanged += ClipboardChangedEvent;
    }

    private void ClipboardChangedEvent(object sender, ClipboardChangedEventArgs e) 
        => ClipboardChangedNotify?.Invoke(this, e);

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (!isDisposed) {
            // Cannot allow to throw exceptions here: add more checks to verify that 
            // the NativeWindow still exists and its handle is a valid handle
            NativeMethods.RemoveClipboardFormatListener(window.Handle);
            window?.DestroyHandle();
            isDisposed = true;
        }
    }

    ~ClipboardUpdateMonitor() => Dispose();

    private class ClipboardWindow : NativeWindow
    {
        public event EventHandler<ClipboardChangedEventArgs> ClipboardChanged;
        public ClipboardWindow() {
            new SecurityPermission(SecurityPermissionFlag.UnmanagedCode).Demand();
            var cp = new CreateParams();

            cp.Caption = "ClipboardWindow";
            cp.Height = 100;
            cp.Width = 100;

            cp.Parent = IntPtr.Zero;
            cp.Style = NativeMethods.WS_CLIPCHILDREN;
            cp.ExStyle = NativeMethods.WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT | NativeMethods.WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW;
            this.CreateHandle(cp);
        }
        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            switch (m.Msg) {
                case NativeMethods.WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE:
                    IntPtr owner = NativeMethods.GetClipboardOwner();
                    var threadId = NativeMethods.GetWindowThreadProcessId(owner, out uint processId);
                    string processName = string.Empty;
                    if (processId != 0) {
                        using (var proc = Process.GetProcessById((int)processId)) { 
                            processName = proc?.ProcessName;
                        }
                    }
                    ClipboardChanged?.Invoke(null, new ClipboardChangedEventArgs(processId, processName, threadId));
                    m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
                    break;
                default:
                    base.WndProc(ref m);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Custom `EventArgs` object used to carry the information collected about the Clipboard Owner:

```
public class ClipboardChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public ClipboardChangedEventArgs(uint processId, string processName, uint threadId)
    {
        this.ProcessId = processId;
        this.ProcessName = processName;
        this.ThreadId = threadId;
    }
    public uint ProcessId { get; }
    public string ProcessName { get; }
    public uint ThreadId { get; }
}
```

`NativeMethods` class:

```
internal static class NativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool AddClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    internal static extern bool RemoveClipboardFormatListener(IntPtr hwnd);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    internal static extern IntPtr GetClipboardOwner();

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    internal static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

    internal const int WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE = 0x031D;

    internal const int WS_CLIPCHILDREN = 0x02000000;
    internal const int WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW = 0x00000080;
    internal const int WS_EX_CONTROLPARENT = 0x00010000;
}
```