# Reliably determine PID of a process that updated clipboard

Tags: go, winapi

When I subscribe to clipboard updates using `AddClipboardFormatListener()` I get `WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE` messages so I can retrieve the clipboard content. The problem is that I fail to retrieve PID of the process that updated the clipboard. When I call `GetWindowThreadProcessId()` passing the handle I got from `GetClipboardOwner()` I receive `ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE` (1400).

Here is the code I use:

```golang
        var msg C.MSG
        for C.GetMessageW(&msg, hwnd, 0, 0) != 0 {
            if msg.message == C.WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATE {
                owner := C.GetClipboardOwner()

                if C.OpenClipboard(hwnd) == 0 {
                    // ...
                    continue
                }

                var pid C.DWORD
                C.GetWindowThreadProcessId(owner, &pid)

                hdata := C.GetClipboardData(C.CF_UNICODETEXT)
                if hdata == C.HANDLE(C.NULL) {
                    // ...
                    C.CloseClipboard()
                    continue
                }

                wstr := C.LPWSTR(C.GlobalLock(hdata))
                content := wstrToGoStr(wstr)
                C.GlobalUnlock(hdata)
                C.CloseClipboard()

                // ...

                handler(int(pid), content)
            }
            C.TranslateMessage(&msg)
            C.DispatchMessage(&msg)
        }
```

What is the problem?

Comment: A PID by itself is useless, since you never know whether its meaning changed between receiving and using it. So then, what's the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I need to get PID of a process that updated the clipboard.

Comment: That's understood. But that PID is useless information. You cannot conceivably rely on it having any particular meaning at any point in time after you received it. So since you cannot used that PID for anything meaningful, what problem are you actually trying to solve?

Comment: I implement some kind of security monitoring, so it's useful for me. The question isn't whether or how is it useful, the question is how to obtain PID.

Comment: There's no "reliable" way, only hacks with lots of possible race conditions: [How to get the process ID or name of the application that has updated the clipboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65151116/how-to-get-the-process-id-or-name-of-the-application-that-has-updated-the-clipbo)

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. Why do I get ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE and how to fix that?

Comment: @SimonMourier, And this question doesn't duplicate the question you mention. The point of this question is different. Why a valid handle that is successfully used to retrieve clipboard data can't be used to obtain PID?

Comment: ERROR_INVALID_WINDOW_HANDLE means the window that was the owner of the copy is not valid any more. There's nothing mysterious about that, it's just unreliable.